# Flutter card to add image and text not center in the card

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm beginner for the flutter. I added two card and image and text, I make a center but its not working correctly, top space and bottom space not same , anyone know how to do that correctly ?
Thanks

[image: image description here]

**code here**

```
Container(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Container(
                                              child: Card(
                                                elevation: 3,
                                                margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                                                ),
                                                color: isNIC?Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.headline1!.color:
                                                Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.color,
                                                child: InkWell(
                                                  onTap: (){
                                                    itemChange( 1);
                                                  },
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60,bottom: 0,),
                                                    height:100,
                                                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                      image: DecorationImage(
                                                        image: AssetImage('assets/icons/ic_id-card.png', ),
                                                        scale:15,

                                                      ),

                                                    ),
                                                    child:
                                                    Text("NIC",
                                                      style: TextStyle(
                                                        fontSize: 14,
                                                        fontFamily: "medium",
                                                        color: isNIC?Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.color:
                                                        Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3!.color,
                                                      ),),


                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),


                                          //Space
                                          SizedBox(width: 15,),
                                          Expanded(
                                            child: Column(
                                              children: [
                                                Card(
                                                  elevation: 3,
                                                  margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)
                                                  ),
                                                  color: isPasport?Theme.of(context).accentTextTheme.headline1!.color:
                                                  Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.color,
                                                  child: InkWell(
                                                    onTap: (){
                                                      itemChange( 2);
                                                    },
                                                    child: Container(
                                                      padding:  EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0,bottom: 0,),
                                                      height:100,
                                                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                        image: DecorationImage(
                                                          image: AssetImage('assets/icons/ic_passport.png', ),
                                                          scale: 15,

                                                        ),

                                                      ),
                                                      child: Text("Passport",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                          fontSize: 14,
                                                          fontFamily: "medium",
                                                          color: isPasport?Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2!.color:
                                                          Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3!.color,
                                                        ),),
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decorationImage` works as a stack, the child widget of the container will be added on top of that image(as a stack), so it won't work as you want, actually if you opened the widget inspector you will see that what actually moved the Text('NIC') down is the padding you added to that container `padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60,bottom: 0,)`. So what you need to do is this:

```
Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                        elevation: 3,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                        color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.color,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Container(
                            height: 100,
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 50,
                                  child: Image.asset(Constants.LOGO_ICON),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "NIC",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontFamily: "medium",
                                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline3.color,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  //Space
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 15,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 3,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
                      color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.color,
                      child: InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        child: Container(
                          height: 100,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 50,
                                child: Image.asset(Constants.LOGO_ICON),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Passport",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    fontFamily: "medium",
                                    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline2.color),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

notice that i separated the image from the container so it will be a different widget, now wrap in inside a column, and when you use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center` the widgets will be centered like you want

Comment: Thanks buddy, That's nice, and great explain, thanks for your solution

Comment: this way you have more control over the two widgets, you can align them up or down, add space around or inbetween, etc.

Comment: try both solutions and then decide, it's not a competition! besides, wrapping both with center will do the job the easy way not the right way @anirudh

Comment: @MichaelSoliman how is wrapping withing center "not the right way"

Comment: actually if you looked carefully at your code you will notice that it's almost the same solution, you just used an extra widget where you could have used the ```mainAxisAlignment``` property of the column. also you added your answer without any explanation! but anyway your answer will definitely work, and it is right, mine is more clear that all. @anirudh

Comment: @MichaelSoliman Yeah I agree totally, my only concern was that the user mentioned "I tried but not working correctly" which is absolutely false!

Comment: maybe he meant didn't work as intended that's all

Comment: @MichaelSoliman as far I see both solutions are one and the same.

Comment: @MichaelSoliman maybe that's the case with using `decoration image`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234374/discussion-between-michael-soliman-and-anirudh).

Answer (score 1):

You can add Text widget inside the Center widget as below:

child: Center(Text("NIC", style ..........................))

Comment: After Wrapping inside Center widget, What is the position of the texts(NIC)?

child: Center(child: Text("NIC", style ..........................))

Comment: If you want specific height with respect to Container:
Positioned( top: <20.0>, child: Text("NIC", style ..........................))

Comment: Use Positioned Widget instead of Center widget and give top attribute

If you want specific height with respect to Container -->>
Positioned( top: <20.0>, child: Text("NIC", style ..........................))

Comment: text is center but, image and text overlapping, actually I'm not clear, can you put the solution in answer using answer box?

Comment: Use Positioned Widget

Answer (score 1):

wrap both `Image Container` & `Text widget` inside a `Column Widget` & wrap that column widget inside `Center widget`.

```
child : Center(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //1. the image container code
          //2. the text widget code
        ],
),)
```

Comment: @core114 try this and let me know if you face any more difficulties

Comment: @core114 one more suggestion to avoid this much level of nesting. `Use children: <Widget>[]` instead of child inside a child

Comment: I tried but not working correctly, buddy anyway thanks for your valuable time